# How to skip a playbook in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have two playbooks one is fs.yml and nfs.yml..How can i add these two play books in single playbook and should prompt me which one i need to play. My playbooks pasted below. Tried multiple options but always vars_prompt executing first though tag variable is defined.

```
# cat filesystemcreation.yml
---
# YAML documents begin with the document separator ---

# The minus in YAML this indicates a list item.  The playbook contains a list
# of plays, with each play being a dictionary
-
  vars_prompt:
  - name: HostGroup
    prompt: Enter the Hostgroup to run the playbook
    private: no
    tags:
    - local
  - name: vgname
    prompt: please enter the Volume Group Name
    private: no
    tags:
    - local
  - name: lvname
    prompt: please enter the Logical Volume Name
    private: no
    tags:
    - local
  - name: lvsize
    prompt: please enter the Logical Volume Size in MB
    private: no
    tags:
    - local
  - name: mountname
    prompt: please enter the mountpoint Name
    private: no
    tags:
    - local
  hosts: "{{ HostGroup }}"
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: Creating Logical Volume
    lvol:
      vg: "{{ vgname }}"
      lv: "{{ lvname }}"
      size: "{{ lvsize }}"
    tags:
    - local
  - name: Creating File system
    filesystem:
      fstype: ext4
      dev: /dev/mapper/{{ vgname }}-{{ lvname }}
    tags:
    - local
  - name: Mounting File system
    mount:
      name: "{{ mountname }}"
      src: /dev/mapper/{{ vgname }}-{{ lvname }}
      fstype: ext4
      state: mounted
    tags:
    - local
# Three dots indicate the end of a YAML document
...
```

Comment: Why did you override my edit with handwritten HTML instead of just using the formatting tools?

Answer (score 1):

[Tags](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html) only apply to tasks, and you are using them in vars sections. Also, you have not shown how you are excluding tags, by default all tags run.

There would not be a prompt if you also provided a value of the same name in a location [lower on the precedence list than "play vars_prompt"](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

Personally, I will only use prompts for sensitive information. Ansible is designed for non-interactive use cases, prompts are skipped if not on an interactive shell.

Also consider [moving vars and tasks into a *role* for better reuse.](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html) Provide a defaults/main.yml  file with some reasonable values for your use case.  The playbook can override those vars in a number of different ways.

Comment: i am new to ansible, my requirement is very simple. I have to combine these two playbooks (fs.yml and nfs.yml) . In case if i want to perform nfs related tasks it has to skip file system related task. As you said tags only applies to tasks not to the vars section. If i am going for roles how to skip playbook . Can you advice?

Comment: Edit your question to include the other nfs playbook and why you must skip it. You can target only the specific hosts that need a set of plays, or skip things based on conditions, or design the tasks such that you can run both everywhere.  But the design is easier to explain with a specific problem.    Finally, generalize later: prompt less and hardcode values more. You aren't solving a general purpose make a file system problem.  You are doing a specific thing for this one application.